# Mesh moves back in Edit Mode

Tags: modeling, mesh

I'm having an issue where, for some reason, the mesh moves back in Edit Mode then moves back again when I get off Edit Mode. The model was auto-rigged in Mixamo. Why is this happening? This doesn't happen in the model that wasn't rigged.

Image Refence - [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8mQf6.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Any poses etc. are moving and/or deforming the mesh are doing these operations on top the basic mesh. When you go to *Edit Mode*, the mesh shows its original basic appearance, to put it in simply words. It's the same with modifiers for example, if you take a cube and put a *Subdivision Surface* modifier on it, the cube becomes rounded. But going into *Edit Mode* shows the original basic cube (unless you have set the option to show the modifier effect in *Edit Mode* as well). This is usually useful if you want to tweak or change something general which is easier to do on the basic low-poly cube mesh than on a high-poly mesh.

Comment: In short, I can't make it stay put?

Coz, I was hoping I can tweak the mesh when I've already rigged it. :(

Comment: Well, you have to either tweak it in its basic shape and hope it turns out as you wish or you have to apply the pose so it stays like that, than this vecones the new badic mesh. I guess there is an option in the armature modifier to show the manipulated mesh in Edit Mode, but even if so, everything you change will stay for all poses.